# How can I disable firebase notification on android client app

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to disable firebase notification service when the user turns off notification through settings.

I found questions on this topic:

[Firebase on Android - I want to disable firebase notifications on Android client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511198/firebase-on-android-i-want-to-disable-firebase-notifications-on-android-client)

and

[android FCM enable/disable from application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699708/android-fcm-enable-disable-from-application-settings)

but answers are an alternative way for ignoring notifications.

Is there any other way to unregister firebase notifications.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Use this.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("X");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am not using any topic for notifications to unsubscribe. I want to unsubscribe a particular user.

Comment: from the app o some functions?

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding the usecases of FCM but the fact there's not a more direct way to do this if you don't have topic messaging enabled is really dumb

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, and i don't have a backend service that sends the push notifications through the FCM API.

What i tried and is working is to override the "handleIntent" method on my FirebaseMessagingService implementation and checking there if user disabled notifications or not from the app to handle them.

The working code below:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        // get from shared preferences if notifications are enabled

        val prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE) 
        val notificationsEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("notifications_enabled", false)

        if(notificationsEnabled){
            super.handleIntent(intent)
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately only seems to work for me when the app is in the background,  otherwise Firebase still pops the notification.

Comment: not working to me, FCM auto generate notification when app in background/killed state

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time to find it out how to disable displaying push notifications when app in background. Everything is clear when app in foreground and you can handle everything in the app - when user switched off notifications in app settings, you just don't show notifications. But when app in background, Firebase handle everything somewhere under the hood and you cannot override methods of `FirebaseMessagingService`, because they are final.
I found some very dirty solution and maby someone tell this is silly, but what I did is overrode onCreate of `FirebaseMessagingService` and did next:

```
    private void removePush(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                StatusBarNotification[] notifications = manager.getActiveNotifications();
                for (StatusBarNotification n : notifications) {
                    if (n.getTag().contains("campaign_collapse_key_")) {
                        Logger.logD(TAG + ": Found firebase push. remove it.");
                        manager.cancel(n.getTag(), n.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                manager.cancelAll();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

If this solution help someone - good. If you found better solution, let everyone know ;)